# Change user-id in the ISPF statistics of a PDS member programatically

Tags: mainframe, rexx, ispf

I am trying to change the user-id value of a module within a PDS.

That can be done interactively within ISPF, using menu-option 3.5 (in a non-custome ISPF set-up).

I want to do this using a Rexx program instead.

Comment: like if you want to allocate any ds you can do that with the command ""ALLOCATE DA('"dataset_name"') NEW SPACE(20,50) DSORG(PS) 
RECFM(F,B) LRECL(80) BLKSIZE(800)" . I want the command like this for resetting the id, we can do that with the option 3.5 Reset Ispf Statistics option, but I want the command that I can use in REXX program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will probably be best to use the ISPF Service LMMSTATS.

```
//TSOBATCH EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,DYNAMNBR=40,PARM='ISPSTART CMD(%GENDIAG)'
//ISPPROF  DD DSN=&&T,DISP=(,PASS),SPACE=(CYL,(10,10,10),RLSE),       
//            DCB=(SYS1.PARMLIB)                                     
//ISPMLIB  DD DSN=SYS1.SISPMENU,DISP=SHR                             
//ISPPLIB  DD DSN=SYS1.SISPPENU,DISP=SHR                             
//ISPSLIB  DD DSN=SYS1.SISPSENU,DISP=SHR                             
//         DD DSN=SYS1.SISPSLIB,DISP=SHR                             
//ISPTLIB  DD DSN=SYS1.SISPTENU,DISP=SHR                             
//SYSPROC  DD DSN=&SYSUID..GENDIAG,DISP=SHR                           
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                               
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                               
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                               
//SYSIN    DD DUMMY,DCB=BLKSIZE=80                                   
//SYSTSIN  DD DUMMY,DCB=BLKSIZE=80
/**********************************************************************/
/* RESET ISPF STATS TO USERID ISPF_USERID                     */
/**********************************************************************/
ISPFSTATS:PROCEDURE                                                     
PARSE ARG ISPF_DSN,ISPF_MEMBER,ISPF_USERID                             
ADDRESS ISPEXEC                                                         
"LMINIT DATAID(DATAID) DATASET('"ISPF_DSN"') ENQ(SHR)"                 
"LMOPEN DATAID("DATAID")"                                               
"LMMSTATS DATAID("DATAID") MEMBER("ISPF_MEMBER"),USER("ISPF_USERID")"   
 LMMSTATS_RC=RC                                                         
"LMFREE DATAID("DATAID")"                                               
RETURN LMMSTATS_RC
```

I have pasted the JCL and the code together from here, http://ibmmainframeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=1772, contributed by user ehrocha.

You should locate, freely available from IBM on the internet, the *Interactive System Productivity Facility (ISPF) Services Guide* for your release of z/OS. There you will find the full documentation of LMMSTATS and all the other ISPF Services available.

Comment: It's ehrocha who deserves the thanks, I just did the search-engineing and pasting. That's lots out there if you do a bit of research when you hit an issue.